# CCleaner for Mac / Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, performance, ccleaner

Is there a program for OS X and/or Ubuntu like CCleaner? Memory cleaning and internet cache cleaner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never had much of a need for them, but I listed several Mac OS X tools in [an answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/63154/how-can-i-tune-up-a-somewhat-crusty-mac-osx-10-5-leopard-machine/63349#63349): [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/pgs/english.html), [Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/index.php), [AppleJack](http://applejack.sourceforge.net/), [Cache Out X](http://www.trilateralsystems.com/cacheoutx/), [Yasu](http://jimmitchelldesign.com/yasu/).

Answer (score 6):

A similar question was brought up before but I can't seem to find it. What it boils down to is that Windows works differently when compared to these operating systems. They do not have a registry, and do not run programs in the same manner. I think it's easier to add clutter your system on Windows **if you don't know what you're doing** and really drag down the speed. On Linux and Mac, most things are just flat files. Temporary folders are usually cleared on boot and there aren't all that many of them if you wanted to clear them yourself. There are programs available that will clear these folders for you though. [Onyx](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/20070) for Mac comes to mind as one.

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought of this today - "It's easier to add clutter *to* (Watch the typo there, missing word) your system on Windows"

Answer (score 0):

OS X already has a [set of maintenance scripts](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/hoard/mactips/MacOSX_configuration_tips.html#maintenance) that it runs (daily, weekly and monthly) to clear out caches and rotate logs.

You can download a utility like Onyx to run these whenever you want, or your Mac will just run them on its cron schedule. This keeps your system fairly clean.

To run them manually:

```
sudo periodic daily weekly monthly
```